# Compartment Search is not working in Hapi Fhir JPA Server

Tags: hl7-fhir, hapi-fhir

I am using Hapi FHIR Jpa Server implementation for R4. I was trying compartment search on this server. It is throwing error. I am using Generic Client to perform compartment search.

```
response = client.search()
  .forResource(FamilyMemberHistory.class)
  .withIdAndCompartment("b3126407-6d25-4fc1-a8b2-d0d6f629be92", "Patient")
  .returnBundle(Bundle.class)
  .execute();
```

I have registered `LoggingInterceptor` to my GenericClient to see how request is getting formed. It looks like `http://localhost:8090/fhir/FamilyMemberHistory/b3126407-6d25-4fc1-a8b2-d0d6f629be92/Patient`. When Hapi Fhir JPA Server receives this request, it is throwing following error.

```
2020-05-13 14:03:49.033 TRACE 52512 --- [io-8090-exec-10] c.u.f.r.s.method.SearchMethodBinding     : Method public ca.uhn.fhir.rest.api.server.IBundleProvider ca.uhn.fhir.jpa.rp.r4.FamilyMemberHistoryResourceProvider.search(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,ca.uhn.fhir.rest.api.server.RequestDetails,ca.uhn.fhir.rest.param.StringAndListParam,ca.uhn.fhir.rest.param.StringAndListParam,ca.uhn.fhir.rest.param.StringAndListParam,ca.uhn.fhir.rest.param.TokenAndListParam,ca.uhn.fhir.rest.param.TokenAndListParam,ca.uhn.fhir.rest.param.UriAndListParam,ca.uhn.fhir.rest.param.UriAndListParam,ca.uhn.fhir.rest.param.HasAndListParam,ca.uhn.fhir.rest.param.TokenAndListParam,ca.uhn.fhir.rest.param.StringAndListParam,ca.uhn.fhir.rest.param.TokenAndListParam,ca.uhn.fhir.rest.param.DateRangeParam,ca.uhn.fhir.rest.param.TokenAndListParam,ca.uhn.fhir.rest.param.TokenAndListParam,ca.uhn.fhir.rest.param.ReferenceAndListParam,ca.uhn.fhir.rest.param.UriAndListParam,ca.uhn.fhir.rest.param.ReferenceAndListParam,ca.uhn.fhir.rest.param.TokenAndListParam,ca.uhn.fhir.rest.param.TokenAndListParam,java.util.Map,java.util.Set,ca.uhn.fhir.rest.param.DateRangeParam,java.util.Set,ca.uhn.fhir.rest.api.SortSpec,java.lang.Integer,ca.uhn.fhir.rest.api.SummaryEnum,ca.uhn.fhir.rest.api.SearchTotalModeEnum) doesn't match because ID is not null: FamilyMemberHistory/b3126407-6d25-4fc1-a8b2-d0d6f629be92
2020-05-13 14:03:49.033 TRACE 52512 --- [io-8090-exec-10] ca.uhn.fhir.rest.server.ResourceBinding  : Handler public ca.uhn.fhir.rest.api.server.IBundleProvider ca.uhn.fhir.jpa.rp.r4.FamilyMemberHistoryResourceProvider.search(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,ca.uhn.fhir.rest.api.server.RequestDetails,ca.uhn.fhir.rest.param.StringAndListParam,ca.uhn.fhir.rest.param.StringAndListParam,ca.uhn.fhir.rest.param.StringAndListParam,ca.uhn.fhir.rest.param.TokenAndListParam,ca.uhn.fhir.rest.param.TokenAndListParam,ca.uhn.fhir.rest.param.UriAndListParam,ca.uhn.fhir.rest.param.UriAndListParam,ca.uhn.fhir.rest.param.HasAndListParam,ca.uhn.fhir.rest.param.TokenAndListParam,ca.uhn.fhir.rest.param.StringAndListParam,ca.uhn.fhir.rest.param.TokenAndListParam,ca.uhn.fhir.rest.param.DateRangeParam,ca.uhn.fhir.rest.param.TokenAndListParam,ca.uhn.fhir.rest.param.TokenAndListParam,ca.uhn.fhir.rest.param.ReferenceAndListParam,ca.uhn.fhir.rest.param.UriAndListParam,ca.uhn.fhir.rest.param.ReferenceAndListParam,ca.uhn.fhir.rest.param.TokenAndListParam,ca.uhn.fhir.rest.param.TokenAndListParam,java.util.Map,java.util.Set,ca.uhn.fhir.rest.param.DateRangeParam,java.util.Set,ca.uhn.fhir.rest.api.SortSpec,java.lang.Integer,ca.uhn.fhir.rest.api.SummaryEnum,ca.uhn.fhir.rest.api.SearchTotalModeEnum) does not match
2020-05-13 14:03:49.033 DEBUG 52512 --- [io-8090-exec-10] ca.uhn.fhir.rest.server.ResourceBinding  : Looking for a handler for ca.uhn.fhir.rest.server.servlet.ServletRequestDetails@25b24c89
2020-05-13 14:03:49.033  WARN 52512 --- [io-8090-exec-10] c.u.f.r.s.i.ExceptionHandlingInterceptor : Failure during REST processing: ca.uhn.fhir.rest.server.exceptions.InvalidRequestException: Invalid request: The FHIR endpoint on this server does not know how to handle GET operation[FamilyMemberHistory/b3126407-6d25-4fc1-a8b2-d0d6f629be92/Patient] with parameters [[]]
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the Hapi library constructs the search URL the wrong way around. I would have expected your code to result in a `GET [base]/Patient/[id]/FamilyMemberHistory`, because a compartment search should list the compartment (i.e. Patient) first.

Perhaps you can work around this by switching the resource types in your code?

Comment: Yes you are right. It constructed wrong URL. However, I tried `GET [base]/Patient/[id]/FamilyMemberHistory` on my Hapi FHIR JPA Server by Postman. It is not working and throwing a similar error. I think Hapi FHIR JPA Server does not support Compartment Search.

Answer (score 0):

As you have pointed out in your comment, the HAPI FHIR JPA Server implementation does not support Compartment Search. Please see [this post](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/hapi-fhir/pU61hNqw6p0/discussion) in the HAPI FHIR Google Group in 2017.

If you wish to return all the FamilyMemberHistory resources for a particular patient, the FamilyMemberHistory Resource does offer a [search parameter](https://www.hl7.org/fhir/familymemberhistory.html#search) of `patient`:

`[base]/FamilyMemberHistory?patient=[id]`

Example:

`http://hapi.fhir.org/baseR4/FamilyMemberHistory?patient=697321&_pretty=true`

Comment: Yes, Compartment Search and Search Parameter approach produces the same output. However, I wanted to try the compartment search technique to get fhir resources. Now, it seems I have to stick with Search Parameter approach.